I can not query from chromadb server
client = chromadb.HttpClient(host='localhost', port='8000')
template = """
Answer the question based only on the following context:
{context}
Question: {question}
"""
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)
langchainChroma = Chroma(client=client, collection_name='mytest', client_settings=settings,
                         embedding_function=embedding)

rever = langchainChroma.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 5})
print(langchainChroma.similarity_search("what is the chroma"))
chain = (
        {"context": rever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
        | prompt
        | llm_local
        | StrOutputParser())
resp = chain.invoke("what is the chroma")
print(resp)

the resp:
The provided text does not specify what the chroma is, so I am unable to answer this question from the provided context.


Why can't I find data from the database? My database has data
I want to retrieve information from the database and return it to the user. What I saw before was' chroma. from_documents() '. But data processing and querying are separate. I can't get the document
